# How could I custom routing with areas in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on asp.net mvc 3. I am trying to implement the project with areas. i am facing problems with routing. I have folder structure like, `projectName/areas/Dashboard/` and in my DashboardAreaRegistration.cs

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Default_Dashboard",
                "Dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

so my routing looks like, `localhost:56788/Dashboard/Dashboard/Index` here i need my routing should looks like `localhost:56788/Dashboard/Index` for that i have written like,

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Default_Dashboard",
                "Dashboard/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "Dashboard", controller = "Dashboard", action = "PatientPortal", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[]{typeof(Controllers.DashboardController).Namespace}
            );

context.MapRoute(
                "Default_Dashboard",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "Dashboard", controller = "Dashboard", action = "PatientPortal", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[]{typeof(Controllers.DashboardController).Namespace}
            );
```

but no use none of them doesnt work for me that means it shows resource not found error. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try install the [Route Debugger nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) it may help you see why things aren't matching

Comment: I have used it but i didnt find any clue. I have 3 areas for that i need to give 3 diff routings?